# SQL query to find all Data by date range which falls between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Task Table
id  name    start_date  expiry_date
1   Task 1  09-05-2016  11-05-2016
2   Task 2  10-05-2016  13-05-2016
3   Task 3  11-05-2016  12-05-2016 
4   Task 4  17-05-2016  20-05-2016
5   Task 5  18-05-2016  26-05-2016
```

I need to find all the task from a given date range where each date from range falls between start_date and expiry_date. suppose input is 10-05-2016 to 12-05-2016.

```
id  name    start_date  expiry_date
1   Task 1  09-05-2016  11-05-2016
2   Task 2  10-05-2016  13-05-2016
3   Task 3  11-05-2016  12-05-2016
```

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE
 start_date <= '12-05-2016'
 AND expiry_date >= '10-05-2016'`

Comment: It's a shame if mySQL does not support `BETWEEN` EDIT: mySQL does support `BETWEEN` and I read this question wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this condition to [check if two date ranges overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325964/2203084):

```
WHERE 
    StartA <= EndB 
    AND EndA >= StartB
```

Your query should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE
    start_date <= '12-05-2016'
    AND expiry_date >= '10-05-2016'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that start_date is always less than expiry_date

```
SELECT * FROM Task WHERE start_date <= '12-05-2016' AND expiry_date >= '10-05-2016'
```